# google sheets macro how to define a range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, range

I have a spread sheet with a value that represents all the non empty cells in a column. I would like to use this to set a number of formulas in different columns to autofill up to that number of cells. I am looking at googles macro api and confused about how to set this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

here's my code and confusion

```
  number_of_skus = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
 
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('F2:F27'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('G2').activate();
```

In my example the value of `A1=25` rows.

- How do I set the `getRange` attribute to do that?  `getRange('F2:F number_of_skus')` ?

Comment: Would you mind posting an example of what you have and what you want? I don't fully understand the question.

Comment: ```getRange(`F2:F${number_of_skus}`)```